# Internal server error in bakup of magento 1.8.1

Tags: magento

Taking System backup System->tools->backup -> System Backup in admin panel of magento 1.8.1, following Internal server Error occurred ---

---

Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@eshopsnet.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

---

During backup maintenance mode message show on home page of live website. After refreshing browser above error occured in home page and admin panel.

Please provide any solution.

Answer (score 0):

connect to the ftp using software (ex:filezilla) go to the root folder (ex:public_html) right click on `index.php` and select `file permissions`. Then set the `Numeric value` to the 644. your done :)